# Как обойти проблему с CORS при попытке загрузить данные с помощью брузерного javascript кода?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Как обойти проблему с CORS при попытке загрузить данные с помощью брузерного javascript кода?
Ниже приведен рабочий код. Если поменять значение url на https://ftx.com/api/markets , то код возвращает ошибку приведенную ниже. Конечная задача с веб страницы с помощью javascript напрямую загружать данные с API бирж и отображать их.

> Access to fetch at 'https://ftx.com/api/markets' from origin
> 'http://localhost:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Рабочий код

```
//let url = ''https://ftx.com/api/markets''
let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'

  fetch(url, {
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*', 
          'content-type':'application/json'
        }
      }).then(function (response) {
        // The API call was successful!
        return response.json();
  }).then(function (data) {
        // This is the JSON from our response
        console.log(data);
  }).catch(function (err) {
        // There was an error
        console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
  });
```

Comment: У вас есть три варианта 1 - Использовать браузерное расширение. 2 - написать свой прокси бакенд. 3- использовать существующий прокси сервисы

Comment: Если я Linux подыму прокси, то что мне нужно в коде модифицировать, чтобы заработало все ? или нужно менять настройки веб сервера? Я хочу минимально использовать бекенд.

Comment: Надо будет слать запросы на ваш прокси сервер

Comment: Не совем понятно как с javascript прогонять запросы на удаленной сервер. :(

Comment: Непонятно, как сервер сделать или как запрос с браузера послать?

Comment: Если я правильно понял идею с прокси, то чтобы избежать разработки кода на бекенде, я должен 1) поднять реверс прокси на сервере. Можно будет использовать nginx. 2) На веб странице прописать локльные линки на реверс прокси nginx. 3) на прокси прописать меппинг локальных ссылок на API бирж. В этом случае браузер пользователя будет забирать данные с API биржи через реверс прокси, а клиентский javascript код будет визуализровать графики на стороне клиента по данным загруженным посредством прокси  Вся идея в том, что я хочу максимально минимизировать требования к веб серверу и потребляемому трафик

Comment: Желательно не отправлять с локалхоста
Если не помогло попробуй скачать расширение CORS Unblock для chrome